# Showing field value on top of line symbol in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, arcgis-online

In browsing through the Living Atlas Layers in ArcGIS Online, I discovered a layer of tornado data that represents tornado intensity and path using lines of varying color and thickness with a number on top of the line to show its magnitude:

[image: tornado data]

I have hail data in ArcMap that I'd like to reproduce this effect with. How do I use the Magnitude field in the attribute table (referring to hail size) to produce a similar effect?

This is what I currently have:

[image: starting point]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with some label placement rules and label symbology.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create mid point by use of [vertices to point](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) tool. Label magnitude field in mid points.