# ArcGIS Online - How to show field value on line symbol

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online

I have a question, similar to this one:

[Showing field value on top of line symbol in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218066/showing-field-value-on-top-of-line-symbol-in-arcmap)

How do I reproduce this effect (field value on top of line symbol) in **ArcGIS Online**?

[image: effect to reproduce]

**EDIT:**

I looked through the Change Symbol [image: change symbol] option but could not find anything for dropping labels on top of the lines, just various ways to change the line width, color, and field to represent.

Comment: @rumski20 - see edit above.

Answer (score 1):

In the web Mapp viewer, select the content button.

Find the layer that you want to create the labels for.

Select the more information option (the 3 dots) all the way to the right

then select create labels. 
It will give you option to label it by value fields.

Comment: Can I style the label like shown above?

Comment: Styling is very limited on the Online Map Viewer, hopefully one of the things that will be changed by ESRI in the near future. You can place the field names on the line, colors bold italic underline etc...

Comment: How did the user in the above example do it?

Comment: I am not sure, are you positive they used arcgis online web maps?

Comment: Is this map interactive, or is this a static map?

Comment: It was a map I pulled from the ArcGIS Online Living Atlas Layers.